# Update Object Value In Array In NeDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, nedb

I am looking for some help as to how to update a specific object value within an array using NeDB.

I am creating a Node.js web app that needs to use NeDB as it's database. Not sure if you need this info, but I also have the following dependencies in the package.json file:

bcrypt: ^5.1.0,
body-parser": ^1.20.2,
connect-ensure-login: ^0.1.1,
dotenv: ^16.0.3,
express": ^4.18.2,
express-session: ^1.17.3,
jquery: ^3.6.4,
mustache-express: ^1.3.2,
nedb: ^1.8.0,
nodemon: ^2.0.22,
passport: ^0.6.0,
passport-local: ^1.0.0,
path: ^0.12.7

In essence the NeDB database allows users to sign up and follows this template for each entry:

{username: username, password: password, achievements: [{name: name, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: name, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: name, type: type, achieved: achieved}]}

I want to be able to access a specific user and update the achieved value of a specific achievement.

For example I have the following users in the database, and I want to update userOne's achievement one achieved value. How would I go about doing this?

{username: userOne, password: password, achievements: [{name: one, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: two, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: three, type: type, achieved: achieved}]}

{username: userTwo, password: password, achievements: [{name: one, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: two, type: type, achieved: achieved}, {name: three, type: type, achieved: achieved}]}

I have tried using dot notation and object notation and had expected that to work, but nothing changed. I tried to find someone else who was having the same issue as me, but I have hit a dead end.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.